# Web form-when person input ID it gives result

Tags: html, json, for-loop, webforms

I got table in excell that I converted to json..now **how to make web form that person write their ID to input and on submit it gives him only his result** (excel got lot of people so by ID it should return only of specific person data from that document) ..how to make it with for loop or? In index I putted

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action=""> //*does in here goes json document or I attach it in head?*
  OIB: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Ulaz">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Exampe JSON:

```
[
    {
        "FIELD1": "A",
        "FIELD2": "B",
        "FIELD3": "C"
    },
    {
        "FIELD1": "Datum",
        "FIELD2": "Firma ",
        "FIELD3": "Kom"
    },
    {
        "FIELD1": "42740",
        "FIELD2": "NITEH d.o.o.",
        "FIELD3": "11"
    },
    {
        "FIELD1": "42765",
        "FIELD2": "DT Mikša d.o.o.",
        "FIELD3": "1"
    },
    {
        "FIELD1": "42780",
        "FIELD2": "AUTOTRANSPORT d.d.",
        "FIELD3": "11"
    },
    {
        "FIELD1": "43041",
        "FIELD2": "NITEH d.o.o.",
        "FIELD3": "21"
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you have an example JSON-data?

Comment: `[
 {
   "FIELD1": "A",
   "FIELD2": "B",
   "FIELD3": "C"
 },
 {
   "FIELD1": "Datum",
   "FIELD2": "Firma ",
   "FIELD3": "Kom"
 },
 {
   "FIELD1": "42740",
   "FIELD2": "NITEH d.o.o.",
   "FIELD3": "11"
 },
 {
   "FIELD1": "42765",
   "FIELD2": "DT Mikša d.o.o.",
   "FIELD3": "1"
 },
 {
   "FIELD1": "42780",
   "FIELD2": "AUTOTRANSPORT d.d.",
   "FIELD3": "11"
 },
 {
   "FIELD1": "43041",
   "FIELD2": "NITEH d.o.o.",
   "FIELD3": "21"
 }
]`

Comment: Do you have your JSON available in your javascript or just server sided?

Comment: I converted it from csv  to json online..and excel doc is at my pc..not online

Comment: Which one of the given properties is the `ID`? `FIELD1`? If so its kinda confusing that in index 1 the name is `"FIELD1": "Datum",`.  A Datum (Date) has nothing todo with an ID

Comment: Yeah..I didnt add id part still..but how it convert date to some strange number? Maybe it wasnt converted good.I used http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm

Comment: It's hard to help your without giving me any data to reproduce something. for example the csv-file you are using (with placeholder data of information you are not allowed to provide).

Comment: Do you have mail for contact that I could sent you?

Comment: @zeropublix I sent u mail.